# How to hide a tab in Angular Bootstrap UI using ng-show/ng-hide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular Bootstrap UI to show a tabset. The script I include is ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js and some template html files.

here is my markup:

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-hide="!hideme">
        <tab-heading>
            tab1
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            tab content 1
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab ng-hide="hideme">
        <tab-heading>
            tab2
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            tab content 2
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

here is my controller

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.hideme = true;
});
```

This code does not work (the 2nd tab does not hide).
What is the catch to apply ng attribute to a custom directive?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `tab` directive creates a new scope, so need to use `$parent` to access the model. Try

```
ng-hide="$parent.hideme"
```

Comment: The only problem now is if the 1st tab is hide, 2nd tab is showing, the content of 1st tab is still showing as active.

Answer (score 2):

First Solution: Use both ng-show and ng-hide

```
<tabset>
<tab ng-show="hideme">
    <tab-heading>
        tab1
    </tab-heading>
    <div>
        tab content 1
    </div>
</tab>
<tab ng-hide="hideme">
    <tab-heading>
        tab2
    </tab-heading>
    <div>
        tab content 2
    </div>
</tab>
```

Second Solution: Write a directive

```
.directive("hideTab", function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
            $(elm).css("display", "none");
        });
    };
});
```